# SMS-оповещения в 1С: Управление торговлей

Tags: 1с, sms

Появилась необходимость отправлять уведомления клиентам о начислении и списании бонусных баллов при оплате в розничных продажах.

Т.е. клиент в магазине делает покупку, сообщает свой номер или дает бонусную карту кассиру, которая привязана к клиенту в базе. Продавец пробивает чеку и в итоге в чекам ККМ происходит начисление баллов за покупку.

SMS-рассылки и уведомления в системе настроены и оповещают клиентов об оплате и других изменениях в статусах, но не в розничных продажах, а оптовых (1С считает онлайн-покупки оптовыми).

Работаем с 1С Управление торговлей 11.4.3.137, платформа 8.3.11.3034.

Кто знает как быть?

Comment: Писать свой алгоритм, который будет формировать СМС и отправлять пользователю. Не сложно. Можно реализовать через расширение.

Answer (score 1):

> SMS-рассылки и уведомления в системе настроены и оповещают клиентов об
>   оплатах и других изменениях в статусах, но не в розничных продажах, а
>   оптовых (1С считает онлайн-покупки оптовыми).

Каким образом у вас настроено SMS-оповещение? Это стандартная компонента УТ? В таком случае вы можете вызвать её при пробивании/проведении чека ККМ, достаточно посмотреть вызов в том документе, где есть настройка её вызова. Вероятнее всего, в неё можно вставить собственный шаблон текста, который вы можете создать для начисления или снятия/возврата бонусных баллов.

В любом другом случае рекомендую статью на Инфостарте по поводу четырёх простых способов отправки SMS из 1С, если вам захочется написать обработку отправки без использования стандартных алгоритмов - https://infostart.ru/public/313780/